# Why are movie captions called "subtitles"?

Tags: etymology

[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/subtitle) defines subtitles as both

> A subordinate title of a published work or article giving additional information about its content.

and

> Captions displayed at the bottom of a cinema or television screen that translate or transcribe the dialogue or narrative.

The former is (I think) self-evident ([sub](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sub#Latin) in Latin means, among other things, under). For example, it is evident that a subtitle follows a title (e.g. in a book). However, I see no connection with the second definition. This is, why are captions called subtitles? Which is the origin of this association? According to the definition above, captions transcribe the main text of a script. Yet, you would not call the main text of a book its subtitles would you?

Neither the aforementioned dictionary, nor [Wikisource](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/subtitle), nor [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtitle_(captioning)#History) offer an explanation of the origin of this association.

Comment: Captions displayed at the bottom. Compare subscripts.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Not sure what you mean.

Comment: sub in Latin means, among other things, under

Comment: Also see [Surtitles](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surtitles) and [Intertitles](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intertitle)

Comment: This article goes in depth: Read it all. Enjoy! http://www.transedit.se/history.htm

Answer (score 1):

According to etymonline.com

***[Subtitle](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=subtitle)***

> subtitle (n.)
>   also sub-title, 1825, "subordinate or additional title, usually explanatory," in reference to literary works, from sub- "under" + title (n.). **Applied to motion pictures by 1908**. As a verb from 1858. Related: Subtitled.

Comment: But that explains only the normal subtitle under a title, not the movie captions.

Answer (score -2):

The title of a movie generally appears in the middle of the screen. Sub-titles appear at the bottom of the screen, below the placement of the movie's title.

Comment: Umm.. not really what was asked for..

Comment: Is this a guess? Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: It is not a guess. Anyone who has ever seen a movie with sub-titles knows from observation that the sub-titles almost invariably appear at the bottom of the screen whereas the movie's actual title almost never appears there. The OP is well aware that "sub" means below in Latin. Sub-titles in a movie normally appear below where the actual title of the movie normally appears.

Comment: So you think sub title means below the title? My belief  is that the text itself is the "title" and the sub indicates that it is shown at the bottom. As for why the text itself would be called a title maybe a hangover from the title cards shown in silent movies?

Comment: @Martin You may be correct about silent movies although the dialogue screens were shown as distinct frames. But my point is not why "titles" is included in a noun denoting printed dialogue shown at the bottom of the screen. My point is why "sub" is included in that noun.

Comment: @MartinSmith But text in silent movies was not shown at the bottom. For example, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1279&v=mUvu4wSb0j4) (as "chapters" of the story) and [here](https://youtu.be/BuocVLKdSqQ?t=23m32s) or [here](https://youtu.be/mpjEyBKSfJQ?t=1m33s) (as transcription of words). I found [this example](https://youtu.be/mOGuRCwVCD0?t=16m54s) though where there is main text at the centre and "subtitle" at the bottom (but this might be a latter addition to the movie). In any case, if this is the case, it is not clear why the main text is called "title".

Comment: @lucho Text in silent movies was shown on [intertitles](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intertitle) also known as titles. I didn't claim that it was shown on the bottom. My speculation was explaining the "title" not the sub. it should be clear why titles shown at the bottom might be known as sub titles.

Comment: When the intertitle moved to the bottom of the screen, **below** the scene, it became a subtitle.

Comment: Interesting this was bashed so much. I came here with the same question you answered. Your interpretation is really the only thing that makes sense.

Comment: When downvotes are not explained (which is usually), they can be for any reason whatsoever. In this case, it seems that several people thought the issue was why the word "title" was used for text.